# Updating loaded models with JS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

To explain my exact use-case:
So I have a news-model with a 'created_at' field. Displaying all the dates with an ArrayController works fine and as expected. But what I want to do now, is converting these dates into fuzzy times with http://pragmaticly.github.io/smart-time-ago/ (or http://timeago.yarp.com/).
The problem here is, I need to call `$('.timeago').timeago('refresh');` once the timestamps are loaded and displayed. That seems to work fine as long as I navigate within the ember-app. But when I refresh a site the plugin somehow can't convert it.
So I suppose the command doesn't get called at the right time from the app.
I am doing that in the following two ways right now:
in the View:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
    $('body').timeago('refresh');
}
```

and in the Controller:

```
updateFuzzyTime: function(){
    $('body').timeago('refresh');
}.observes('content')
```

When I do it in either place with the `setTimeout()` command set to 1000ms it obviously does work.

So how can I get ember to perform that command when a model is fully loaded and displayed on a refresh?
(In another project I had a similar issue and there I used the `rerender()` command which did work, but in this use-case I simply can not do that)

Edit: Just to post it here as well. The plugin looks at the datetime-attribute of a time element. So my hbs code looks like this:

```
<time class="timeago" {{bindAttr datetime="date"}}>{{date}}</time>
```

And I suppose the reason why most hooks don't work is because even though the DOM is rendered I suppose Ember hasn't updated the attribute yet.

Comment: Does anyone else have any idea? Or is that a missing future, sort of having an callback event for bindAttr?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it in an `afterRender` callback. That usually executes after everything else.

```
init: function() {
  this._super();
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'updateFuzzyTime');
}

updateFuzzyTime: function() {
  $('body').timeago('refresh');
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't seem to work and I think the problem is that I use the following code: `<time class="timeago" {{bindAttr datetime="date"}}>{{date}}</time>` and the plugin looks at the datetime attribute. So I am guessing, the DOM is completed rendering but the attribute hasn't been set yet. Any other ideas? Though that is really interesting what you posted. You always learn something new. And you did point me in a good direction let's see what I can find.